# Excuting ssh-agent results in 'mkdtemp: private socket dir: permission denied'

Tags: windows-10, ssh-agent

I am unable to ssh from Windows 10 into a Linux machine using key pairs.  The following is in the log

```
debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: The socket is not connected
```

When I try to run ssh-agent from the Windows command prompt I see the following

`mkdtemp: private socket dir: permission denied`

I installed the latest version of OpenSSH for Windows, OpenSSH 8.3p1-1, but still see this message.  I am thinking ssh-agent is unable to create a temporary directory, but I don't know where.  How can I debug why running ssh-agent is failing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was caused by incorrect permissions on `C:\Windows\tempinst` folder.

[Lenovo proposes follow steps](https://support.lenovo.com/gb/en/solutions/ht510153-lenovo-system-update-may-fail-to-start-windows-10):

> Open a command prompt as administrator.
>
> Issue the following commands:
>
> - `takeown.exe /f c:\windows\tempinst /a /r /d y`
> - `rd /s c:\windows\tempinst /q`

In the my case it wasn't enough, I solved this by giving my account write permissions on this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Solution2:

If you have version of Windows git <= 2.30

updating it to 2.40 might solve the problem even when

Solution1:

> Fixing rights
> C:\Windows\Temp
> C:\Windows\tempinst
> C:\Program
> Files\Git\tmp
> %TMP%

is not.